# ExcelのPPMT関数をPHPで再現したい

Tags: php, excel

[ExcelのPPMT関数](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/ppmt-%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0-c370d9e3-7749-4ca4-beea-b06c6ac95e1b)をPHPで再現したいのですが、どうしても同じ値が出ません。
chatGptに散々聞いて試したのですが、違う値が出ます。
PHPでExcelと同じ値を導き出したいです。

Excelは以下の条件になります。

---

=D2+PPMT(B7,1,($B$1+1-A7),D2)

D2 = 10000
B7 = 8%
B1 = 5
A7 = 1

Excel上の値 : 8295.44

---

=C7+PPMT(B8,1,($B$1+1-A8),C7)

C7 = 8295.44
B8 = 9%
B1 = 5
A8 = 2

Excel上の値 : 6481.48

---

どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 書きかけでも構わないので、自分自身で試した PHP のコードを質問に追記してください。